# MySQL cannot update the rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my selected row of data but i could not update it. Once i run the code I am getting this output `{"RowCount": 0 ,"results": []}`. Supposed i should get 1 but i am not getting it. Can i know how to solve this problem.

This is my PHP code:

```
case 'updateStudent':
$studentUpdateSQL = "UPDATE srs_student SET surname=:surname, forename=:forename,
                    email=:email WHERE studentid=:id";
$rs = new JSONRecordSet();
$retval = $rs->getRecordSet($studentUpdateSQL, 'ResultSet',
          array(':surname'=>$surname,
                ':forename'=>$forename,
                ':email'=>$email,
                ':id'=>$id
            ));
echo $retval;
break;
```

This is the JSONRecordSet class:

```
function getRecordSet($sql, $elementName = "ResultSet", $params = null) {
    $stmt     = parent::getRecordSet($sql, $params);
    $recordSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $nRecords = count($recordSet);
    if ($nRecords == 0) {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = json_encode(array("text" => "No records found"));
        $result = '[]';
    }
    else {
        $status = 'ok';
        $message = json_encode(array("text" => ""));
        $result = json_encode($recordSet);
    }
    return "{\"RowCount\": $nRecords ,\"results\": $result}";
  }
 }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed the `JSONRecordSet` class.

Comment: actually the other cases are working so i think the JSONRecordSet is working fine, but anyways i will post the JSONRecordSet class code

Comment: @Daan i have updated my question with the code

Comment: You are doing a fetchAll in your getRecordSet. You can't use fetchAll with an `UPDATE` statement. It returns `false`

Comment: I see no prepare or execute anywhere, or query.

Comment: fetchAll is typically used with SELECT queries

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could be in the parent.

Comment: I believe that happens in the parents method fred.

Comment: Last I knew, `:bind` required that to be prepared. Or, there's something about PDO I don't know about.

Comment: Bind is not necessary, array of placeholders can be passed directly to `execute()`

Comment: @Vincent That's not what Fred meant (I think). What I think he meant is that it's required to be prepared.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is required to be prepared, but that can still happen in the parent function.

Comment: @Daan i solved it by removing the getRecordSet and replacing it with execute method

Comment: What is in `parent::execute` then I wonder? Which class are you extending BTW?

Comment: i will post the answer @Daan

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = new JSONRecordSet();
$db_conn = pdoDB::getConnection();
$stmt=$db_conn->prepare($studentUpdateSQL);
$retval=$stmt->execute(array(':surname'=>$surname,
              ':forename'=>$forename,
              ':email'=>$email,
              ':id'=>$id));
echo $retval;
```